# Cathing a sql exception coming from a postgres trigger via python/psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, exception, triggers, psycopg2

I discovered this behavior while throwing together a quick and dirty python program and database schema that generates test cases for pgaudit to catch. In short, psycopg2 does not throw an exception if an INSERT or UPDATE "works" but the plpgsql trigger fired by the statement fails with an error.

I've tried all manner of searching here and in Google. Everything I find talks about handling exceptions in python or in the statements executed by psycopg2, but not errors in the triggers fired by statements executed by python.

Versions of everything involved are:

- OS = CentOS 7
- python = 3.6
- postgresql = 9.6
- psycopg2 = 2.8.6

Example:

```
                                         Table "audit_test.visits"
  Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 id       | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('audit_test.visits_id_seq'::regclass)
 tstamp   | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 patient  | integer                  |           |          |
 facility | integer                  |           |          |
 treated  | boolean                  |           |          |
Triggers:
    pat_health BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON audit_test.visits FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_test.update_health()

                                 Table "audit_test.patients"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                     Default
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer |           | not null | nextval('audit_test.patients_id_seq'::regclass)
 name      | text    |           |          |
 ishealthy | boolean |           |          |

create function update_health() returns trigger as $body$
begin
  if new.treated is false then
    update patients set ishealthy = false where patients.id = new.patient;
  elsif new.treated is true then
    update patients set ishealthy = true where patients.id = new.patient;
  end if;
  return null;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

Running the following statement throws an error.

```
mydb=# insert into audit_test.visits (tstamp, patient, treated, facility) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 18, FALSE, 5);  ERROR:  relation "patients" does not exist
LINE 1: update patients set ishealthy = false where patients.id = ne...
               ^
QUERY:  update patients set ishealthy = false where patients.id = new.patient
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function audit_test.update_health() line 4 at SQL statement
mydb=# select * from audit_test.visits;
 id | tstamp | patient | facility | treated
----+--------+---------+----------+---------
(0 rows)

mydb=# \q
```

I'm aware I could fix my problem by using the schema name in the trigger's logic, but that's not what I'm worried about. If I run this same statement from a python program with psycopg2, *no exception is thrown to make the program aware the trigger failed*.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
dbname='mydb',
user='fakeadminlol',
host='myserver',
port=5432,
options='-c search_path=audit_test',)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = '''insert into visits (tstamp, patient, treated, facility) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, {}, FALSE, {});'''.format(1,1)
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as ex:
    print(str(ex))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The above code doesn't give ANY indication of an error in pdb, and the program acts like nothing went wrong. Despite no python errors, the visits table is still empty just like the above example with psql.

```
<<< pdb output omitted for brevity >>>
> /root/testme.py(14)<module>()
-> sql = '''insert into visits (tstamp, patient, treated, facility) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, {}, FALSE, {});'''.format(1,1)
(Pdb)
> /root/testme.py(15)<module>()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> /root/testme.py(16)<module>()
-> cursor.execute(sql)
(Pdb)
> /root/testme.py(21)<module>()
-> conn.commit()
(Pdb)
> /root/testme.py(22)<module>()
-> conn.close()
(Pdb)
--Return--
> /root/testme.py(22)<module>()->None
-> conn.close()
(Pdb)
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb)
```

I've tried looking at documentation for postgresql, python, and psycopg2. Nothing has led me to a solution. How can I detect and handle an error in a postgresql trigger from python?

Comment: That is odd - I get 'psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "patients" does not exist', albeit connecting to Posgresql 10 (I can try 9.6 tomorrow)

Comment: Ah. I found the problem. The plpgsql trigger was returning NULL instead of NEW after performing the update. So that explains why I the row didn't appear in the table. And the psql error happened because of search_path not inlcuding the audit_test schema by default. So the INSERT worked but the trigger failed, but only in psql. This didn't error out in python because the search_path was set to audit_test when the connection was made. So the trigger actually wasn't having schema problems, but was failing due to a bad return value.